# How to run play application as a single JAR file?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I implemented a REST server using Play (so there is no "V" in MVC) but I a wondering How to run play application as a single JAR file?

When I do `activator dist` is does create a jar file however when I run `java -jar myplayapp.jar` it says there is no main class. so I understand what is going on but not sure how to fix this. since I don't know what a main class will be for a play app and not sure what else I need to do to build a standalone jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`activator dist` creates a package, not single jar: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying

The result would be a file like `my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip`

After unpacking you will receive a directory with the play application. There is a `bin` directory, you need to call a `my-app` script, that depends on your system. In my case (mac os) I can run application like `$ sh bin/my-app`

Comment: Hi, Thanks I use Mac as well and yes that works as you described but we use RPM based linux machines on production so say I take the zip file from mac and move it onto RPM based linux machine and run `sh bin/my-app` would that work?

Comment: I do not see why it must not work. If you want to create an RPM package, you can use the SBT plugin for it. I never use it, so only can give you a link to a doc: 
http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/rpm.html 
http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/recipes/play.html

This looks like a big theme